# Which version of PCRE does Apache use for mod_rewrite?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, pcre

Several versions of PCRE are installed on my host.

phpinfo() shows that PHP uses version 8.21. In addition it shows a folder: "pcre-regex=/opt/pcre"

In the shell, when I run

```
/opt/pcre/bin/pcretest -C
```

the server shows more information for 8.21.

When I omit the directory and run

```
pcretest -C
```

the server shows information for PCRE 7.8.

What I'd like to know is which version of PCRE Apache uses for mod_rewrite.

which httpd returned "/usr/sbin/httpd", so I tried

```
ldd /usr/sbin/httpd | grep pcre
```

but that returned nothing.

Thanks in advance for any insights!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be something that's happening on your specific distribution or specific to your server's setup, but apache uses `libpcre` and should link to it (which should appear in ldd):

```
libpcre.so.1 => /lib/libpcre.so.1 (0xb780c000)
```

You may need to rely on your package manager to see what version of the package that file belongs to:

```
/lib/libpcre.so.1 -> libpcre.so.1.2.1

 * Searching for libpcre.so.1.2.1 ... 
dev-libs/libpcre-8.33 (/lib/libpcre.so.1.2.1)
```

It's also possible that you've got 2 pcretests installed, because it's sort of odd that you'd have system libraries in the `/opt/` directory. It may be the place where some libraries end up getting installed in your distribution/setup. Debian's got a `libpcre3` package which installs the library as `/lib/libpcre.so.3.12.1` and the test as `/usr/bin/pcretest`. Ultimately it's going to depend on how httpd was build and what it expects to link to. What does simply `ldd /usr/sbin/httpd` say?

Comment: Jon, thank you very much for your reply. >What does simply ldd /usr/sbin/httpd say? It says "not a dynamic executable", explaining the empty grep... This is a cPanel VPS host. Just a  find / -name libpcre.* gives files all over the place: for instance (1) /opt/pcre/lib/libpcre.so.0.0.1 (2) /lib/libpcre.so.0.0.1 (3) /usr/lib/libpcre.so (4) /usr/local/cpanel/lib/libpcre.so.1 (5) /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib/libpcre.so.1.0.1 (6) /usr/local/src/publicnginx/pcre-8.32/libpcre.pc  So it sounds like finding out what mod_rewrite uses is quite a hunt?

Comment: @playful If you get "not a dynamic executable", then that means `httpd` is statically compiled, meaning all the libraries are compiled directly into the executable. In other words, you won't know what version of libpcre it uses unless you find the guy who compiled it and ask him/her.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a cPanel install, which is my case, [cPanel says](http://forums.cpanel.net/f442/pcre-version-compiled-easyapache-used-mod_rewrite-382512.html#post1540211) that the version of PCRE installed by EasyApache is the one in the /opt folder.